# How can I route my solution into different projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm looking for a solution to be able to store my websites in individual projects, while keeping one project as an entrypoint that can route into those projects.

The ideal setup would be something like the following:

```
- Main (entrypoint)
- Website1
- Website2
- Website3
```

I need this format to allow someone to access their website (ie. `Website1`) as a solution they can run and debug on their own, without having access to the entire application.

Basically, I want to be able to set up a new project, add the reference to the `Main` project, add an entry into my routes, and allow the new project to be built out and tested if it needs to be.

Is this possible?

I've looked at using areas and tried several plugins, but I can't seem to get this working properly. My biggest issue right now isn't routing into the project's controller, as I can get into that action perfectly, but once there, I can't reference any of the ASPX files properly. (I need to be able to reference them within the context of the project *and* the entire solution.)

If anyone could direct me towards other resources or questions I might have missed, I'd appreciate that as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to doe this using a source control program of your choice. Put each website project in a separate folder and reference each website project file to a main master.sln file in a different folder called MasterSolution. Commit it all to source control. Then, for a user that opens Website one only, they just do open project, and go to the Website1 project folder and open the project file for Website1. Your MasterSolution is not opened but always gets the latest code as after the Website1 developer does a commit of his/her Website1 updates.

Comment: This is what I'm already doing, but this doesn't really address the issue of being able to route from one "master" project into that project for the main application.

Comment: Could you word your comment in a different way, not exactly following you.

Comment: My issue isn't about compiling independent solutions into one master solution, but how to compile independent solutions into one master solution *along with* a "routing" project, which I already have setup to do domain and area routing... I just can't access the controllers and views properly within those projects.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think what you are asking is possible then...perhaps consider some pre build scripts to copy what is needed into "mock" projects so that everything compiles correctly and is accessible when you need.